# Django 2.2.4 TypeError at /accounts/login __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, django, authentication, typeerror, init

TypeError at /accounts/login
**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login
Django Version: 2.2.4
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:
**init**() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
Exception Location: E:\Python\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py in _get_response, line 113

```
blogsite/blogsite/urls.py

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include
from django.contrib.auth import views
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView as auth_login
from django.contrib.auth.views import LogoutView as auth_logout

urlpatterns = [

    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('blog.urls')),
    path('accounts/login',auth_login,name='login'),
    path('accounts/logout',auth_logout,name='logout',kwargs={'next_page':'/'})
]
```

```
blogsite/blog/urls.py

from django.urls import path,re_path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.PostListView.as_view(),name='post_list'),
    path('about/',views.AboutView.as_view(),name='about'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)$',views.PostDetailView.as_view(),name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/',views.CreatePostView.as_view(),name='post_new'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/edit/$',views.PostUpdateView.as_view(),name='post_edit'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/remove/$',views.PostDeleteView.as_view(),name='post_remove'),
    path('drafts/',views.DraftListView.as_view(),name='post_draft_list'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/comment/$',views.add_comment_to_post,name='add_comment_to_post'),
    re_path(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)/approve/$',views.comment_approve,name='comment_approve'),
    re_path(r'^comment/(?P<id>\d+)/remove/$',views.comment_remove,name='comment_remove'),
    re_path(r'^post/(?P<id>\d+)/publish/$',views.post_publish,name='post_publish'),


]
```

Comment: I think you may want `auth_login.as_view()`